# jquery mvc modal button to access post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have this modal dialog popup where there's 2 buttons. One is a cancel, and the other is accept. I want the accept button to call a POST Action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toscontainer').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            draggable: false,
            width: 700,
            height: 500,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Terms Of Service",
            buttons: {
                "Accept": function () {
                    console.log('accept');
                    $.post({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/User/TermsOfService/'
                    });
                },
                "Decline": function () {
                    $('.accept').dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I've been using the above code but it's giving me a

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http : // somethinghost:999 /User/%5Bobject%20Object%5D

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong...

Also, in the action, I need a value of either 'true' or 'false'.. what would be the best way to pass it from that button?

I have something like this

```
public ActionResult User(bool accept){
   // process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ajax call instead of post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '/User/TermsOfService/',
    data: $("form#identifier").serialize(),
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.responseText);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a way where i can just point them to a non post action? as the site requires an HTML.AntiForgeryToken(). since the user only needs to click a button to agree, i didn't place it in a form? or is it essential?

Comment: Need you to send data or just want to open the term of services page?
A form is not essential, depend in what are you lookink for. tell me pls.

Comment: this is an useful link about **$.post** you can send the boolean value you need in the controller action
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: well, i already opened the terms of service. my issue is the button generated on the dialog popup needs to call an action to update a flag.

Comment: yeah but it still won't go to the action after clicking the "Accept" button on the dialog..

Comment: I want understand, pls. Did you recive any error or the URL is wrong? Can you post agai your code client server?